# There is no sound from pyttsx if i run the code?

Tags: python, audio, pyttsx3

I use this code but i get no sound can someone help me.

```
import pyttsx3
speaker = pyttsx3.init()
speaker.say('hello there')
speaker.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to work. If you are running it on an online IDE, like Replit, it will not work

Comment: If the point of running that code was only to get text-to-speech working alongside your Python code, you can use **Jupyter online** (both classic & JupyterLab) to get your own system to speak the text by passing it via javascript to your local system's Speech synthesis, see [here](https://mindtrove.info/jupyter-tidbit-run-and-say-done/) for examples of code that works. Those approaches run in notebooks in sessions launched from the first two tiles [here at Try Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/try).